# React.js global variables erasing on routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.js, and am trying to figure out how to properly use global variables.

Here I have a global variable defined in App.js along with imports

`window.$cart = ""`

When I'm changing it in another page of my website, it properly changes to whatever I want, but when my React-router redirects a user to another page on some click, like:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

It seems like this global variable Redefines itself back to an empty string.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: If the entire page is reloaded when you switch page, everything will of course be reset. With react-router, it is possible to re-route without reloading the page. Could you provide the code where you perform the re-route?

Comment: Here's an example of my router:
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/ru" component={Ru} />
</Switch>
</Router>

Here's an example of how I access those routes:
<a className="navbar_items" href="ru">Главная</a>

There's plenty of code, so I give you only the example. Every other re-route is made the same way

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to perform the re-route in a way which doesn't reload the entire page. If the page is reloaded, all global variables will of course be reset.

If you use any of the following, the entire page will be reloaded:

```
<a href="ru"/>
window.location = "ru"
```

Instead, you should access the `history` object which is provided by react-router, and then call:

```
history.push('ru')
```

You can read [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)
 about how to retrieve the history object.

Comment: Getting an error: "Invalid hook call"
here's the code:

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

class Navbar_ru extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let history = useHistory();
    return (
              <a onClick={history.push('/ru')} className="navbar_items">Главная</a>
     )

Comment: Hooks can only be used in a function component, not a class. I would recommend reading about hooks on the react docs. For class component, the higher order component withRouter from react router should be used.